# How to handle Deadlocks while committing the batchExecute of a PreparedStatement in Java

Tags: java, mysql, transactions, prepared-statement, deadlock

The code is getting data from a queue, adding it to a prepared statement as batch, executes the batch and then commits:

```
int counter = 0;
while (!this.dataQueue.isEmpty()
        && counter <= config.MAX_FLUSH_COUNT) {
    DataRecord record = this.dataQueue.poll();
    if (record.ip.length() > 40) {
        record.ip = record.ip.substring(0, 40);
    }
    try {
        this.dataFlush.setInt(1, record.uid);
        this.dataFlush.setInt(2, record.fid);
        this.dataFlush
                .setTimestamp(3, new Timestamp(record.time));
        this.dataFlush.setString(4, record.ip);
        this.dataFlush.addBatch();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.logError("Error building record: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    counter++;
}
if (counter > 0) {
    try {
        this.dataFlush.executeBatch();
        this.dataFlush.getConnection().commit();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Log.logError("Error executing flush: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This flush might contain thousands of entries (limited to 2000 per batch by MAX_FLUSH_COUNT) so a deadlock sometimes happens (flush is executed every 8 seconds and deadlocks occur around every 5 to 6 hours).

Edit: This is my Prepared statement:

```
Connection conn = DBBase.getConnection();
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
this.snatchFlush = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO slog (uid, fid, time, ip) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fid=VALUES(fid), time=VALUES(time), ip=VALUES(ip)");
```

uid is the primary key of this table.
Database Engine is InnoDB, no foreign keys, no triggers.
The table might be read from or written to by the webserver as well as by this application at the same time which is very unlikely but possible.

My first change will be to split up the batch into multiple batches and limit their size to 200-500 datasets.

My problem now: When a deadlock occurs, the usual solution is to restart the transaction.

Does this mean I have to re-add the data to the dataFlush Prepared Statement, executeBatch and commit again? If yes, that would mean that I need to save the data polled from the queue because it would be lost otherwise.

Is there any better solution that would not require me to save the polled data? (I am assuming a simple executeBatch and commit in the catch-Block would not work, since executeBatch removes the batch data).

Comment: Please show SQL command this code executes in a batch. Please also show structures of tables involved in this transaction (a primary key, indexes, engines - InnoDB or MyISAM ?) . Are there any foreign keys in the table ? Are there any triggers fired on this transaction that modify data in other tables (but especially tables referenced by foreign keys) ?

Comment: I added information about the database structure, foreign keys, triggers and usage.